# Query of Queries or a loop with grouping

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a table which holds information on messages sent between users. It looks something like this:

```
MessageID | MessageIDReference | MessageSubject   | Body     | Date
1           NULL                 Test               Hello      10/01/2014
2           1                    RE: Test           Goodbye    11/01/2014
3           1                    RE: Test           Hello      11/01/2014
.......
50          45                   RE: Subject        Blah       12/12/2014
```

So the first message created will have a `NULL` value in the `MessageIDReference` column (because its a new message not a reply). When a user replies to a message it inserts the `MessageID` of the original message into the `MessageIDReference` column so that we know which message its in reply to. Nice and simple!

On my webpage I want to display the first message in the conversation, followed by any subsequent replies to that message within one area so its easy to see the flow of conversation, like such:

```
<ol>
<cfloop query="messages">
<li>
  #MessageSubject# #Body#
      <ol>
      <!--- I want replies to this message here somehow --->
      <li>1st reply</li>
      <li>2nd reply</li>
      etc etc
      </ol>
</li>
  </cfloop>
<ol>
```

I thought it could be done with some kind of group by within each of the `<cfloop>` tags but I'm not sure how. I now think it has to be done using Query of Queries in the inner loop so that it returns all the replies per `MessageID` and outputs those.

Query of Queries works when I do something like this:

```
<cfquery name="Messages">
    SELECT * FROM Messages
    </cfquery>

<ol>
  <cfquery type="query" name="MessagesNew">
    SELECT *
    FROM Messages
    WHERE MessageIDReference IS NULL
    </cfquery>
  <cfloop query="MessagesNew">
  <li> #MessagesNew.MessageSubject# #MessagesNew.Body#
    <cfquery type="query" name="MessagesReplies">
    SELECT *
    FROM Messages
    WHERE MessageIDReference = #MessagesNew.MessageID#
    </cfquery>
    <ol>
      <cfloop query="MessagesReplies">
      <li>#MessagesReplies.MessageSubject# #MessagesReplies.Body#</li>
      </cfloop>
    </ol>
  </li>
  </cfloop>
</ol>
```

Comment: You might be better off not nullifying the MessageIDReference on new messages.  Instead, make it the same as the MessageID.  It would certainly make this task easier.  By the way, your query of queries sample will only work if there is only one message without a reference.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have edited my post so its a bit more clear. I was rushing before and didn't finish my example

Comment: Why would you rush on a question?

Comment: @volumeone, are you on Twitter or other social media?

Comment: hi Adam I'm not using them much but I have a Facebook account. I could create a Twitter account I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Dan makes a great suggestion, but here is a query that will work to get the original message as well as any replies - sorted so first row is the original message and the rest would all be replies in chronological order.

```
<cfquery type="query" name="MessagesReplies">
    SELECT *
    FROM Messages
    WHERE MessageIDReference = <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_integer" value="#MessagesNew.MessageID#" />
    OR MessageID = <cfqueryparam cf_sql_type="cf_sql_integer" value="#MessagesNew.MessageID#" /> 
    ORDER BY MessageId, date
</cfquery>
```

The query you run where MessageIDReference is NULL will return the first message in every thread, so you need to select that one based on the ID.

Notice the use of `cfqueryparam`, you should ALWAYS parameterize your queries. Always.

Comment: The order by date part might not be necessary if the messageid field is autoincrement.

Answer (score 1):

This way is probably easier.

```
<cfquery name = "GetMessages" datasource="something">
select MessageId, ifnull(MessageIDReference, MessageId) Message
, other fields
from your message table
where whatever
order by Message, MessageId
```

```
<cfoutput query="GetMessages" group = "message">
#grouped data#
<cfoutput>
 #ungrouped data#
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Note that the ifnull function is database specific.  You didn't specify your database engine.  If whatever you are using does not have an equivalent function, you can use this

```
case when MessageIDReference is not null MessageIDReference
else MessageId end Message
```

Also note that your problem is more complicated than you might think.  Lets say that you only want data from a certain date range.  If so, you will want to filter it further to include only those threads that started in that date range.  A subquery will probably work, but I'll give you a chance to work that out on your own.

Comment: FWIW, try [`coalesce`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE) for a more database neutral alternative. It is not an exact equivalent, but tends to have broader support than vendor specific functions like `ifnull`,`isnull` and the like.